# How to write 2 strings on same line in Java

Tags: java, string, drjava

I have written a code in Java to compute the area and circumference of a circle. When I want to print the output, I can not do the following:

```
"The area of a circle with a radius of" +radius "is" +area
```

Instead, it prints like:

```
"The area of a circle with a radius of" +radius
"is" +area
```

Thank you in advance for possible solutions.

Comment: Please add the code.

Comment: Add a + between `radius` and `"is"`. String concatenation is a little arcane in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"The area of a circle with a radius of" + radius + "is" + area
```